# Different results achieved using Python's os.walk function and ls command

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-2.7

```
#!/bin/python
import os
pipe=os.popen("ls /etc -alR| grep \"^[-l]\"|wc -l")         #Expr1
a=int(pipe.read())
pipe.close()
b=sum([len(files) for root,dirs,files in os.walk("/etc")])  #Expr2
print a
print b
print "a equals to b ?", str(a==b)  #False
print "Why?"
```

What is the **difference** between **Expr1**'s function and **Expr2**'s?
I think **Expr1** gives the right answer, but not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:**

`ls -laR | grep "^[-l]"` counts symlinks to directories.
It matches any line that begins with `l` and that includes symlinks to directories.

In contrast, `[files for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/etc')]`
**does not count symlinks to directories**. It ignores all directories and lists only files.

---

**Long answer:**

Here is how I identified the discrepancies:

```
import os
import subprocess
import itertools

def line_to_filename(line):
    # This assumes that filenames have no spaces, which is a false assumption
    # Ex: /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired connection 1
    idx = line.rfind('->')
    if idx > -1:
        return line[:idx].split()[-1]
    else:
        return line.split()[-1]
```

`line_to_filename` tries to find the filename in the output of `ls -laR`.

This defines `expr1` and `expr2` and is essentially the same as your code.

```
proc=subprocess.Popen(
    "ls /etc -alR 2>/dev/null | grep -s \"^[-l]\" ", shell = True,
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE)         #Expr1
out, err = proc.communicate()
expr1 = map(line_to_filename, out.splitlines())

expr2 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    files for root,dirs,files in os.walk('/etc') if files))  #Expr2

for expr in ('expr1', 'expr2'):
    print '{e} is of length {l}'.format(e = expr, l = len(vars()[expr]))
```

This removes names from `expr1` that are also in `expr2`:

```
for name in expr2:
    try:
        expr1.remove(name)
    except ValueError:
        print('{n} is not in expr1'.format(n = name))
```

After removing filenames that `expr1` and `expr2` share in common,

```
print(expr1)
```

yields

```
['i386-linux-gnu_xorg_extra_modules', 'nvctrl_include', 'template-dkms-mkdsc', 'run', '1', 'conf.d', 'conf.d']
```

I then used `find` to find these files in `/etc` and tried to guess what was unusual about these files. They were symlinks to directories (rather than files).

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur elaborate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use walk, errors are ignored (see [this](http://docs.python.org/library/os.htm)), and ls sends a message for each error. These count as words.

Comment: The error messages would be sent to standard error, not the pipeline.

Comment: And also if all goes well, you have .. and . to count on ls. Also it has to be ls -alR /etc ...

Comment: '''sum([len(files) for root,dirs,files in os.walk("/etc",onerror=some_function)])''' is this able to get the correct answer? and what to do with "some_function"?

Answer (score 0):

On my machine, /etc is a symlink to /private/etc, so `ls /etc` has only one line of output. `ls /etc/` give the expected equivalence between `ls` and `os.walk`.

Comment: /etc is used as an example.in fact it could be any directory. and these 2 expressions often gives different answers.

Comment: What kind of crazy distro are you running that symlinks /etc?

Comment: @Falmarri  NeXTStep or descendant e.g. OSX. iOS